# Error that variable isn't defined in python

Tags: python, variables

i'm trying to get the user to select a folder.
When I press a button in the tkinter window I want it to run the following code.

```
def getFilePath():
    global fullFileName
    FileDir=filedialog.askdirectory(title = "Select Folder")
    fullFileName.set(FileDir)
    print(fullFileName)
```

I'm getting the error that 'fullFileName' isn't defined. This will be the directory path of the selected folder.

Any help appriciated. Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't `fullFileName.set(FileDir)` just be `fullFileName=FileDir`?

Comment: Not if it's an instance of one of the TKinter "var" types (used to keep track of the text held within a GUI widget). However, that needs to have been set up before the function is run. We need to see more code than this to be able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable in the global scope. You are trying to set the variable which is not declared.

```
fullFileName = ''
def getFilePath():
    global fullFileName
    FileDir=filedialog.askdirectory(title = "Select Folder")
    fullFileName.set(FileDir)
    print(fullFileName)
```

Another alternative if you don't want `fullFileName` in global scope then you can try:

```
def getFilePath():
    FileDir=filedialog.askdirectory(title = "Select Folder")
    fullFileName=FileDir
    print(fullFileName)
```